# Checkbox javascript activan input

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Tengo dos `checkbox`, uno para autorizar un registro y otro para rechazarlo. Quiero que cuando este marcado el de rechazar me habilite un `select` que viene por defecto con el atributo `disabled` con algunas opciones, lo he logrado a medias, el detalle es que debo marcar primero autorizar y después rechazar para que se habilite el `select` o bien marcar y desmarcar el check de rechazar y no entiendo por que no lo hace a la primera.
Adjunto un fragmento del código para que se puedan realizar pruebas.

```js
function uncheck(autorizar, rechazar, comentario) {
  var checkbox1 = document.getElementById(autorizar);
  var checkbox2 = document.getElementById(rechazar);
  var comentario = document.getElementById(comentario);
  checkbox1.onclick = function() {
    if (checkbox1.checked != false) {
      comentario.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      checkbox2.checked = false;
    }
  }
  checkbox2.onclick = function() {
    if (checkbox2.checked != false) {
      checkbox1.checked = false;
      comentario.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input onclick="uncheck('autorizar14','rechazar14','comentario14')" type="checkbox" id="autorizar14" name="autorizar[]" value="14"></td>
    <td><input onclick="uncheck('autorizar14','rechazar14','comentario'14)" type="checkbox" id="rechazar14" name="rechazar[]" value="14"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="comentario" id="comentario14" disabled="disabled">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Motivo 1</option>
        <option value="2">Motivo 2</option>
        <option value="3">Motivo 3</option>
        <option value="4">Motivo 4</option>
        <option value="5">Motivo 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input onclick="uncheck('autorizar15','rechazar15','comentario15')" type="checkbox" id="autorizar15" name="autorizar[]" value="15"></td>
    <td><input onclick="uncheck('autorizar15','rechazar15','comentario15')" type="checkbox" id="rechazar15" name="rechazar[]" value="15"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="comentario" id="comentario15" disabled="disabled">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Motivo 1</option>
        <option value="2">Motivo 2</option>
        <option value="3">Motivo 3</option>
        <option value="4">Motivo 4</option>
        <option value="5">Motivo 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: por que le pasas 3 parametros a la funcion?

Comment: Hola igmer, lo hago porque los input y select  los tengo dentro de una fila de una tabla, osea puedo tenerlos en mas filas, a cada una de esas filas les asigo un id de la siguiente manera: autorizar+numerofila, rechazar+numerofila, comentario+numerofila.   y son los que envio como parametros, de esa manera la funcion logra identificar la fila a la cual debe afectar.

Comment: Bienvenido. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben de incluir un [mcve] pero en tu HTML no se incluyen las etiquetas de `table` ni `tr` que deberían incluirse en una tabla y quizás falten otras cosas. Si el código `php` no es necesario para reproducir el problema, considera sustituir esa parte, quizás por algún valor estático.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario Ruben realize los ajustes mencionados.